# Angular 9 + Angular Material Mat table updating one record

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, mat-table

I cannot find a solution according to my case so I created this question.

I have a mat table to display data. I have signalR to push the data change from backend. So the data updating is very often.

I have a context menu on my mat table. Right click to show a drop down.

The issue is, whenever there is a change, I fetch the new data and do something like below:

```
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(newdata);
```

This refreshes the table. But, the context menu will disappear by the time the table refreshes.

How to just update one record when SignalR called? But not refreshing the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
this.dataSource.data = newdata;
```